Why would a 64-bit Operating System be slower than a 32-bit?
I am installing PHP on a Raspberry Pi model 3A+.
When building on a 32-bit version of the Raspberry Pi OS, the build took around 8 minutes.
Building on a 64-bit OS has taken 30 minutes so far and is not yet finished.
Can anyone opine with their experience as to whether this is reasonable, or any possible fixes ?
My best guess is a 64-bit system handles larger variable sizes, and thus the time taken to transport them through the system is longer.

"When building" - what are you building? You start by stating that you install PHP, but then the issue is with "building" something. My opinion is that the 3A+ with its pitiful 512MB ram is useful for running software, not building it, especially using 64bit OS

By build I refer to the process of downloading the PHP source code, then running 'make' followed by 'make install'. This process, when using a 32-bit version of the OS, I found efficient. Not so with a 64-bit. Why this is the case is my question.

Whats wrong with the packaged PHP? Anyway, as I said, the 3A+ running 64bit does not really have enough RAM to do such intensive work as compiling anything too big

64-bit systems usually require more RAM (because pointers to memory locations are larger) which may become important if you do not have infinite amount of memory when doing large tasks. I would start with checking how much the systems swap.
